# twig replace and raw is not working correct

Tags: twig

I have twig code

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $('#{{ setting.name|e }}').editable({
                            {% if setting.options is not empty %}
                            source: {{ setting.options|raw }},
                            {% endif %}
                            value: '{{ setting.value|replace({"\n": "", "\r\n": "", "\t": "", "\n\r": ""})|raw}}',
                            placement: 'bottom',
                            pk: '{{ setting.id }}',
                            url: '{{ siteUrl('/admin/settings/edit/' ~ setting.id ) }}',
                            ajaxOptions: {type: 'post'}
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```

this code

```
value: '{{ setting.value|replace({"\n": "", "\r\n": "", "\t": "", "\n\r": ""})raw}}'
```

is not working when input html tags within textarea

```
value: '    &lt;div id=&quot;disqus_thread&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;'
```

should

```
value: '    <div id="disqus_thread"></div>;
```

How i can fix issue?

Comment: Can you please add code with where you create `setting` or `setting.value` variable?

Comment: setting.value is in my database in setting table

Comment: when use value: '{{ setting.value|raw}}' it is correct but with value: '{{ setting.value|replace({"\n": "", "\r\n": "", "\t": "", "\n\r": ""})|raw}}' is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set that:

```
value: '{{ setting.value|replace({"\n": "", "\r\n": "", "\t": "", "\n\r": ""})|raw}}'
```

You forget set `|` before `raw`.

EDIT:
This is work. I set this:

```
    {% set val = "sdfg sdfg sdfg
s dfg
<p>

 sd fg
 </p>" %}
{{ val }}
```

Output:

```
sdfg sdfg sdfg
s dfg
&lt;p&gt;

 sd fg
 &lt;/p&gt;
```

Set:

```
{% set val = "sdfg sdfg sdfg
s dfg
<p>

 sd fg
 </p>" %}
{{ val|replace({"\n": "", "\r\n": "", "\t": "", "\n\r": ""})|raw }}
```

Output:

```
sdfg sdfg sdfgs dfg<p> sd fg </p>
```

Comment: here I forget | my code on website is value: '{{ setting.value|replace({"\n": "", "\r\n": "", "\t": "", "\n\r": ""})|raw}}'